# Integral involving Laguerre Polynomial and Bessel Function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I am curious to know if a closed form expression can be given for the
integral,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\, dx\, e^{-cx} (\sqrt x)^r J_s (b \sqrt{x}) L_m^\gamma(cx) L_n^\lambda(cx)\nonumber  
\end{equation}

Following cases are known,

1)  $r = s = \gamma + \lambda$ [Koelbig et al, J. 
Comput. Appl. Math. 71 (1996) 357]. Gradshteyn or Prudinikov also tabulate this case albeit with wrong result.

2) $r = s$ [Shukla et al, Commun. Korean Math. Soc. 27 (2012), No. 4, 721]